# Channels & Memory Management Strategies for Large Objects

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, clr, c#-3.0

I'm trying to determine how to best implement .Net Core 3 Channels and whether it's a good idea to pass very large objects between tasks.  In my example, one task that is very fast can read in a 1GB chunk from a very large file.  A number of consumer tasks can read a chunk from the channel and process them in parallel, as processing is much slower and needs parallel (multi-threaded) execution.

In testing my code, there is a massive amount of GC happening and total RAM used far exceeds the sum of all data waiting in one bounded channel and all executing tasks.  I've simplified my code down to the most basic example hoping someone can give me some tips on how to better allocate/manage memory or if this approach is a good idea?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Channels;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MergeSort
{
    public class Example
    {
        private Channel<byte[]> _channelProcessing;

        public async Task DoSort(int queueDepth, int parallelTaskCount)
        {
            // Hard-code some values so we can talk about details
            queueDepth = 2;
            parallelTasks = 8;

            _channelProcessing = Channel.CreateBounded<byte[]>(queueDepth);

            Task[] processingTasks = new Task[parallelTaskCount];
            int outputBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
            for (int x = 0; x < parallelTaskCount; x++)
            {
                string outputFile = $"C:\\Output.{x:00000000}.txt";
                processingTasks[x] = Task.Run(() => ProcessChunkAsync(outputBufferSize));
            }

            // Task put unsorted chunks on the channel
            string inputFile = "C:\\Input.txt";
            int chunkSize = 1024 * 1024 * 1024; // 1GiB
            Task inputTask = Task.Run(() => ReadInputAsync(inputFile, chunkSize));

            // Wait for all tasks building chunk files to complete before continuing
            await inputTask;
            await Task.WhenAll(processingTasks);
        }

        private async Task ReadInputAsync(string inputFile, int chunkSize)
        {
            int bytesRead = 0;
            byte[] chunkBuffer = new byte[chunkSize];

            using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(inputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                // Read chunks until input EOF
                while (fileStream.Position != fileStream.Length)
                {
                    bytesRead = fileStream.Read(chunkBuffer, 0, chunkBuffer.Length);

                    // Fake code him to simulate the work I need to do showing outBuffer.Length is calculated at runtime
                    Random rnd = new Random();
                    int runtimeCalculatedAmount = rnd.Next(100, 600);
                    byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[runtimeCalculatedAmount];

                    // Create the buffer with a slightly variable size that needs to be passed to the channel for next task
                    byte[] outBuffer = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 1024 + runtimeCalculatedAmount];
                    Array.Copy(chunkBuffer, outBuffer, bytesRead);
                    Array.Copy(tempBuffer, 0, outBuffer, bytesRead, outBuffer.Length);

                    await _channelProcessing.Writer.WriteAsync(outBuffer);
                    outBuffer = null;
                }
            }

            // Not sure if it's safe to .Complete() before consumers have read all data from channel?
            _channelProcessing.Writer.Complete();
        }

        private async Task ProcessChunkAsync(int outputBufferSize)
        {
            while (await _channelProcessing.Reader.WaitToReadAsync())
            {
                if (_channelProcessing.Reader.TryRead(out byte[] inBuffer))
                {
                    // myBigThing is also a very large object (result of processing inBuffer and slightly larger)
                    MyBigThing myBigThing = new MyBigThing(inBuffer);
                    inBuffer = null;

                    // Create file and write all rows
                    using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create("C:\\Output.txt", outputBufferSize, FileOptions.SequentialScan))
                    {
                        // Write myBigThing to output file
                        fileStream.Write(myBigThing.Data);
                    }
                    myBigThing = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See if you can rent buffers using `ArrayPool.Rent` instead of creating new giant ones. Can't you create your `outbuffer`, do what you need to do with it and then read your file chunk directly into it without having to create a temp reading buffer?

Comment: I'm researching ArrayPool.Rent now as I wasn't familiar with it.  You're 100% right about the second part and I'm embarrassed I didn't consider it.  In my code, I read in a fixed amount and then search for the next 0x0A ('\n' character) and append it to the buffer.  There isn't a strict requirement for that, so I can actually just read back for the previous 0x0A since all I'm trying to do is make sure the buffer ends at a line break.  I can do exactly as you suggested and just read directly into the outBuffer and send the next task the offset to stop reading from the buffer.  Thanks so much!